# How to get rows which selected by user in telerik rad grid?

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I hava a `Rad Grid` like this :

```
   <tel:GeneralRadGrid ID="MainGridView" runat="server" AllowMultiRowSelection="True" 
            OnItemCommand="MainGridView_OnItemCommand"
            GroupingEnabled="false"
            OnItemCreated="MainGridView_OnItemCreated"
            MasterTableView-CommandItemSettings-ShowAddNewRecordButton="false"
            DataSourceID="GridDataSource">
            <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="Id">
                <Columns>
                   <telerik:GridClientSelectColumn  runat="server" UniqueName="ClientSelectColumn"   >
                   </telerik:GridClientSelectColumn>

                   <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="mNumber" HeaderText="<%$Resources:Public,Number%>" UniqueName="Number" HeaderStyle-Width="10%" FilterControlWidth="80%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />

                   <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="<%$Resources:Public,NikName%>" UniqueName="Name" HeaderStyle-Width="17%" FilterControlWidth="80%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />                     
                </Columns>
            </MasterTableView>

            <ExportSettings IgnorePaging="True" ExportOnlyData="True"></ExportSettings>
        </tel:GeneralRadGrid>
```

I added `AllowMultiRowSelection="True"` and `<telerik:GridClientSelectColumn  runat="server" UniqueName="ClientSelectColumn" > </telerik:GridClientSelectColumn>`
 for selecting multi rows, but i can not get selected rows,
How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Where do you want to get the selected rows - on the client or on the server?

On the client you can use the **get_selectedItems()** method on the RadGrid client-side object.

On the server you can use the **SelectedItems** property which returns a GridItemsCollection.

Comment: SelectedItems returns 0 items if Rebind() was used on the grid